# Python: Removing elements from list that is a value in a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

`a = dict()`

`a["A"] = [1,2,3,4,5]`

`a["B"] = [1,2]`

I want to iterate through each value (in this case in the form of a list) in the dictionary and if the number of elements in the list is greater than 2, I want to remove all the elements after the second element.

For example, after I alter the values, my dictionary should be:

`a["A"] = [1,2] # [3,4,5] are removed from this value`

`a["B"] = [1,2]`

I tried:

`del a["A"][3:len(a[2])]`

But this returned:

`[3, 4, [1, 2, 3]]`

Two questions:
1) Why is the output of my attempt the way it is?
2) How would I correctly implement what I am trying to do?

Thanks!

Comment: `del a["A"][3:len(a[2])]` raises a `KeyError`. In fact it's pretty hard to transform `[1,2,3,4,5]` into `[3,4,[1,2,3]]` into a single expression, since assigning to a slice wouldn't insert a sublist.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/del.html by the way, what a[2] is?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way of implementing what you want is "writing it literally":

```
for value in dictionary.values():
    del value[2:]
```

Which could be read as:

> for every value in the dictionary, remove all elements after the
>   second.

Note that:

- This solution does *not* create a new dictionary, it modifies the original dictionary in-place
- This solution does *not* create new lists. It modifies the current lists in-place.

In certain circumstances you may want to create a new dictionary and/or avoid mutating the values of the dictionary, in this case you should avoid using `del` and instead re-assign the sliced values:

```
dictionary[key] = value[:2]
```

---

It seems also the most efficient:

```
In [1]: %%timeit
   ...: a = {'A': [1,2,3,4,5], 'B': [1,2]}
   ...: for value in a.values():
   ...:     del value[2:]
   ...: 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 663 ns per loop
In [2]: %%timeit
   ...: a = {'A': [1,2,3,4,5], 'B': [1,2]}
   ...: for key, value in a.items():
   ...:     a[key] = value[:2]
   ...: 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 920 ns per loop
In [3]: %%timeit
   ...: a = {'A': [1,2,3,4,5], 'B': [1,2]}
   ...: for value in a.values():
   ...:     if len(value) > 2:
   ...:         del value[2:]
   ...: 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 796 ns per loop

In [4]: %%timeit
   ...: a = {'A': [1,2,3,4,5], 'B': [1,2]}
   ...: a = {k:v[:2] for k,v in a.items()}
   ...: 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.15 us per loop
```

*If* most of the values are of length 2 or shorter, then adding an `if len(value) > 2:` to slice only when necessary might give a *slight* increase in performances.
If you expect most values to be longer than 2 then it only increases overhead.

---

Regarding your first question:
Doing `del a["A"][3:len(a[2])]` does *not* give `[3, 4, [1, 2, 3]]` as output.
You get a `KeyError: 2`. You have done something else if you obtained that output.

Comment: Nice solution. The user should be aware of the fact that trim_dictionary is modifying the original lists.

Comment: Your timing methods are not standard - and you are using `items` instead of `iteritems` to emulate my answer (which throws it off) not to mention your dataset is very limited.

Comment: @InbarRose I'm using python3 so `items()`  is *the* correct method. Also, I don't see how the timing method is "not standard". `timeit` is *the* module that you must use to profile little benchmarks, `ipython` gives a simple interface to that module.

Comment: Your solutions are doing different jobs, each with its peculiar side effect. It doesn't make so much sense comparing their performances... Both solutions are nice.

Answer (score 1):

Use this function:

```
def trim_dictionary(d, trim=2):
    return {k:v[:trim] for k,v in d.iteritems()}
```

Example:

```
>>> trim_dictionary({'A':[1,2,3,4], 'B':[5,6], 'C':[7,8,9], 'D':[10]})
{'A': [1, 2], 'B': [5, 6], 'C': [7, 8], 'D': [10]}
```

Comment: Nice solution. The user should be aware of the fact that trim_dictionary is replacing old values (lists) with new ones

Answer (score 0):

Use a dict comprehension:

```
>>> {k: [item for item in v if item <= 2] for k, v in a.iteritems()}
{'A': [1, 2], 'B': [1, 2]}
```

To modify the original dict:

```
for k, v in a.iteritems():
...     v[:] = [item for item in v if item <= 2]
...     
>>> a
{'A': [1, 2], 'B': [1, 2]}
```

To keep just the first two items in each list:

```
for k in a:
    a[k] = a[k][:2]  #or del a[k][2:]
...     
>>> a
{'A': [1, 2], 'B': [1, 2]}
```

Comment: might be more compact using itertools.filter()

Comment: for modifying the original dictionary, is there a reason you use v[:] instead of v?

Comment: I'd prefer LC over `filter` with lambda.

Comment: @user2241856 `[:]` is used to modify the same object, you can also do: `a[k] = [item for item in v if item <= 2]`

Comment: Thanks for explaining that. I have one more question: In your solution, you only keep elements if they are <= 2. What if my elements were not only limited to integers? Is there a way to remove elements beyond a certain index?

Comment: Is this correct? I believe it doesn't satisfy: "if the number of elements in the list is greater than 2, I want to remove all the elements after the second element." Why are you comparing the elements of the list with 2?

Comment: OP's question seems to ask to keep only up to the first two elements in value. Recommend this: `{k:v[:2] for k,v in a.iteritems()}` or `for k in a: a[k] = a[k][:2]`

Comment: `for v in a.values(): del v[2:]` should be the simplest way of doing it.

Comment: @user2241856 you can use slicing then: `k: v[:2]` or `a[k] = a[k][:2]`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
del a["A"][3:len(a[2])]
```

Use

```
a["A"] = a["A"][:2]
```

or

```
del a["A"][2:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get the (max) first two elements.

```
a["A"] = [1,2,3,4,5]
a["B"] = [1,2]
a["C"] = [1]
for key in a:
    a[key] = a[key][:2]
```

If you have a lot of data it might be faster to check the length of the list.

```
for key, value in a.items():
    if len(value) > 2:
        a[key] = value[:2]
```

Method 3 is using `del`:

```
for value in a.values():
    del value[2:]
```

All examples tested on Python 3.